# ask user for permission on analytics

Tags: ios, analytics, appstore-approval, flurry

Based on the privacy requirements from the ios store, can we include analytics like Flurry and track app usage without asking the users permission? The analytics doesn't get user personal data or device data, just details on how they use the app.

1. Privacy

*Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and
providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used

*Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth,
in order to function will be rejected

*Apps that target minors for data collection will be rejected

Comment: I'll 2nd that motion. I have worked with several apps in the app store that use flurry and do not ask permission. Assuming you use Flurry as intended and are not transmitting any personally identifiable information, you should have no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that uploads my activity, no matter what the activity, should have my permission to do so.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it, when you use applications like Angry Birds, Cut The Rope, etc. They are all gathering your usage statistics, without you knowing.

Comment: Haha... yeah, like the time Angry Birds told me I unlocked the 15 hour playing time achievement... I don't play Angry Birds that much... do I? ;)

Answer (score 0):

No data that cah help you to identify user can be sent without permission. But common data can be.  How about Game Center? A lot of achievments are connected with data collecting about users interactions.